# I am unable to resize image using this API

Tags: html, css, image

I am using NASA api, but I am unable to resize the image. Its not working using either internal, inline or external. I am able to style paragraphs and other elements.
The image is being stored in ID content1

```
<h1>
      API Template
    </h1>
    <div id="content1"></div>

    <p>
    <div id="content2">
      

    </div>
```

The code below is the script to fetch API:

```
<script>
      
      
      sendApiRequest()


    //An asynchronous function to fetch data from the API.
    async function sendApiRequest(){
      let API_KEY="mMt3hOGtbFkQeywFo48d1tpQw9rvEclGizRgzhBL"
      let response = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${API_KEY}`);
      console.log(response)
      let data = await response.json()
      console.log(data)
      useApiData(data)
    }


    //function that does something with the data received from the API. The name of the function should be customized to whatever you are doing with the data
    function useApiData(data)
    {
  
      document.querySelector("#content1").innerHTML += `<img src="${data.url}">`
    }


    </script>
```

I am unable to make changes to the image..

```
#content1
{
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 7%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is targeting the `div` container, instead of the image itself. Change your CSS selector to `#content1 img`:

```
#content1 img
{
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 7%;
}
```